# Eclipse plug in to edit web.xml in Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a **Java EE web page** and **web.xml** descriptor of the project has not a interactive way to add information like servlet-servlet mapping, etc. all it's only manual

Any plugin of eclipse to edit this automatic, like netbeans or jdeveloper **web.xml** descriptor?

Answer (score 4):

Yes . [JBoss Tool](http://www.jboss.org/tools) is an umbrella project for a set of Eclipse plugins that supports JBoss and related technology such as JSF, (X)HTML, Seam, Hibernate etc. It contains the web.xml editor .See [this](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.2.1.GA/en/visual_web_tools_ref_guide/html/editors.html#GraphicalWebApplicationFileEditor).

[image]

Comment: The second link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Servlets 3.0 in Java EE 6 than you can define servlet url's, filters, security, etc. directly in your code using annotations like @WebServlet, @WebFilter etc.

In Eclipse, if you add the XML Schema definition to the web.xml file than eclipse will tell you what elements are allowed in the place you're editing (after you hit ctrl + space).

Answer (score 0):

I remember Netbean has the capability too.

Comment: yeap, but i don't like netbeans so much, it's soo slowly Dx, but his web.xml descriptor wizard it's great xD