# What is the web xml plugin editor plugin in this example?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, web, eclipse-plugin

I am watching [this vedio](https://youtu.be/qmEVsUJh2d8). What is the web xml plugin for Eclipse to install. [image].   I already installed  WTP.

Comment: This seems to be the web.xml editor of JBos Tools, see the answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912087/eclipse-plug-in-to-edit-web-xml-in-java-ee)

Comment: See my updates. It doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Did you check if the JBoss editor appears under the _Open with_ drop-down menu of the context menu of the web.xml file?

Comment: I did. That's what mentioned in the update, even if I open it that way. I can't see the tree view.

Comment: I installed jboss tool from the eclipse market place

Comment: What is this "tree view" you mention? Is the pictured editor not the one you want? Which one *is* the one you want?

Comment: Never mind. I reinstalled jboss tool and it worked this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot shows the [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) web.xml editor.